# RewriteRule handle two rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

127.0.0.1/ex/main/items/bread

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]+)/?$ /ex/main/item.php?act=view&name=$1 [L]
Works fine
```

But How can I add a second rule ?

127.0.0.1/ex/main/items/bread/123/ to handle both the input and the name

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]+)/?$ /ex/main/item.php?act=view&name=$1&id=$???? [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create capture groups for everything after "bread":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /ex/main/item.php?act=view&name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```